# String character encoding with Android and Oracle Java

Tags: java, android, unicode, character-encoding

I have code which computes the SHA-256 hash of a String, and noticed that I was getting different hashes from Android and Oracle Java 7 for the same string. My hashing code converts the `String` into `byte[]` with:

```
byte[] data = stringData.getBytes("UTF-16");
```

With UTF-16 encoding, I get different results from Oracle Java and Android Java. This is the string I was hashing:

```
// Test Code:
String toHash = "testdata";
System.out.println("Hash: " +DataHash.getHashString(toHash));
```

And get theses hashes with UTF-16:

```
Hash: a1112a0363a59097a701e38398e1fdfef3049358aee81b77ecaad2924a426bc5 [Oracle Java 7]
Hash: 811b723aee07c7a52456fc57a5683e73649075a373d341f7257bf73575111ba3 [Android 2.2]
```

However, with UTF-8, I get the same hash with both JREs:

```
Hash: 810ff2fb242a5dee4220f2cb0e6a519891fb67f2f828a6cab4ef8894633b1f50 [Oracle Java 7]
Hash: 810ff2fb242a5dee4220f2cb0e6a519891fb67f2f828a6cab4ef8894633b1f50 [Android 2.2]
```

Is there some kind of endian-ness issue going on which is causing the different results on the different platforms? How should I really be preparing a String to be hashed in a platform independent way?

**EDIT:**
Whoops, the answer is rather obvious once you read about UTF-16 a bit more. There are two versions of UTF-16 (big-endian and little-endian). You just need to specify which version getBytes() should use, and the hashes are the same. Pick one of:

- UTF-16LE
- UTF-16BE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of Orcale Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html):

> When decoding, the UTF-16 charset interprets a byte-order mark to
>   indicate the byte order of the stream but defaults to big-endian if
>   there is no byte-order mark; **when encoding, it uses big-endian byte
>   order and writes a big-endian byte-order mark.**

That means plain `UTF-16` should always encode as Big Endian in Oracle Java.

Then from [Android Java documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html):

```
Charset            Encoder writes
UTF-16BE           BE, no BOM
UTF-16LE           LE, no BOM
UTF-16             BE, with BE BOM
```

So there is a bug in either one, or in the documentation. Both must be Big Endian, and write BOM, so there shouldn't be any difference.

In general you should prefer `UTF-16BE/LE` over `UTF-16`, but in this case it seems to be a bug.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. It does look like Android (2.2 at least) is doing little-endian conversion:

Oracle Java 7:

    `UTF-16: [-2, -1, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 100, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 97]`

Android Java 2.2:
    `UTF-16: [-1, -2, 116, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 100, 0, 97, 0, 116, 0, 97, 0]`

Comment: @TajMorton `-1, -2, 116, 0..` is Little Endian, with LE BOM. Is that from Android? Anyway, it clearly contradicts with Android documentation.

Comment: Sorry, my formatting got destroyed and I accidentally posted before I was ready. Oracle Java 7 gave `[-2, -1, 0, 116]` with "UTF-16", whereas Android 2.2 gave `[-2, -1, 116, 0]`. So yes, it does look like it's producing LE with a LE BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Show your hashing code, but it is probably doing something wrong. The results of hashing is a `byte[]` so there is no need to convert from string to `byte[]` in the first place. For converting a binary hash value to a `String` use Base64 or hex encoding.